# FCM notification not received whether the app in background or foreground

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman, android-notifications

Am not receiving notification after sending it using firebase notification componser or postman, though I get successful feedback from both

- I have followed firebase docs on how to implement it.
- I have also tried answers for similar questions but still am not
  receiving the notification
- Still when I used postman I got a successful response, but the
  notification dint appear

**AndroiManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.fcmpushnotification">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".helper.MyFirebaseMessageService"
            android:exported="false"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**FCM SERVICE CLASS**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessageService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

      @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        Log.d("FIREBASETOKEN", "testing if method is called ");

        //checking if , there is any notification
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification()!=null) {
            String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
            String message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
            NotificationHelper helper = new NotificationHelper();
            helper.setBody(message); helper.setTitle(title);
            NotificationHelper.displayNotification(getApplicationContext(), helper);
            Log.d("FIREBASETOKEN", "notification is not empty");

        }else {
         //Toast.makeText( , "notification is empty" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("FIREBASETOKEN", "notification is empty");
        }


    }
}
```

Using postman
 *body*
{

```
 "to" : "cI1AZOAfrv8:APA91bFQUcKD6gGIfCHplDXCMCFvgk9K2b-jwsN2g_3omDMM0_y_twT0SpqWYzoBWhzWYhcsedbNZCfsygBqDVT5nECOL9sBM7mKFn_4oxry7H8P_rxVvvPRCTXWitxw4V2xd2Gkbmtb",
 "collapse_key" : "type_a",
 "notification" : {
     "body" : "Body of Your Notification",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification"
 }
}
```

*response*

```
{
    "multicast_id": 6756762729932992317,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": "0:1562751631028566%77e482e477e482e4"
        }
    ]
}
```

I expected to receive a notification and the logs in the `onMessageReceived()`  to be logged , but nothing am getting

Comment: check whether you are entering right token.

Comment: I used the token i get from  `task.getResult().getToken();` but still i dont get the notification

Comment: check permission for internet and internet status

Comment: I have added the permission, but still, am not getting the notification on the phone

Comment: internet permission should be enable, check from application setting

Comment: internet permissions are added, but  `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)` is not called, yet `onNewToken(String s)` in the same class is called when the app is installed for the first time

Comment: whenever you install app for first time, token is updated automatically so you need to copy paste same token to postman body.

Comment: I used the updated token, `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)` is no called

Comment: I will create demo and upload on Git, Will post link here.

Comment: i will be glad, am waiting for the link

Comment: I need some time, If you are in hurry try this https://www.androidhive.info/2016/06/android-getting-started-firebase-simple-login-registration-auth/

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are missing with internet permission.
add following permission to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and internet must be ON on your device.